# Autocomplete like Visual Studio Community

Tags: unity-game-engine, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Community, if a type "game", I get

- **game**Object
- **Game**Object
- Foo**Game**Foo
- AnythingWith**Game**OnIt

In VSCode not, its shows only things that starts with **game** and some weird stuff.

- **game**Object
- **Game**Object
- **G**r**a**dient**M**od**e**

Is there some settings can make it works like VS Community?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by-design. VS Code uses looser matching for suggestions but whole word matches such as `gameObject` of `myGameObject` should always be shown before broken up matches such as `GradientMode`.

There is currently no setting to control this. If you have any suggestions on how this could be improved, please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)